# How to get current date - two weeks date in Java?

Tags: java, date

I have today's date in this string format `2014-05-08` and I needed to get the date of  2 weeks prior the currents date.

So the data I should be getting back is - `2014-04-24`.

```
        String currentDate= dateFormat.format(date); //2014-05-08

        String dateBefore2Weeks = currentDate- 2 week;
```

But I am not sure how do I extract date of two weeks prior to current date in Java?

Comment: This is not *exactly* a duplicate, because times have changed since then.

Comment: @ChrisMartin If something has changed, such as the arrival of [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8, then update the original question(s) and answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Calendar` to modify your `Date` object:

```
//method created for demonstration purposes
public Date getDateBeforeTwoWeeks(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -14); //2 weeks
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Use the method above in your code:

```
String currentDate= dateFormat.format(date); //2014-05-08
String dateBefore2Weeks = dateFormat.format(getDateBeforeTwoWeeks(date));
```

Answer (score 2):

Java now has a pretty good built-in date library, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2014-05-08").minusWeeks(2));
        // prints "2014-04-24"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the date using a SimpleDateFormat into a Date object
2. Use a Calendar object to subtract 14 days from that date
3. Format the resulting date using the same SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

worth having a look into joda-time api [[http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html]](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html%5d).